# How can I query this in CodeIgniter

Tags: mysql, database, codeigniter

This is what I want:

```
SELECT DISTINCT first_name,last_name 
FROM employees e 
INNER JOIN salaries s ON e.emp_no = s.emp_no 
WHERE e.birth_date > '1963-01-01' 
AND s.salary>150000
```

I've tried this and I get the names I want but also an additional 12 names. Something is wrong.

```
    $this->db->distinct();
    $this->db->select('first_name, last_name');
    $this->db->from('employees');
    $this->db->join('salaries s', 'e.emp_no = s.emp_no', 'inner');
    $this->db->where('e.birth_date > 1963-01-01');
    $this->db->where('s.salary > 150000');

    $result = $this->db->get();
```

Comment: You didn't alias `employees` in ` $this->db->from('employees');` Add the `e` after employees like you did for `salaries s`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the where clause, the operator should be entered in the first parameter to be compared with the second parameter, the values.

```
$this->db->where('e.birth_date >', 1963-01-01);
$this->db->where('s.salary >', 150000');
```

Answer (score 2):

I added a comment, but I'll add it as a suggested answer.You didn't alias `employees` in `$this->db->from('employees');` Add the e after employees like you did for salaries s.

```
$this->db->distinct();
$this->db->select('first_name, last_name');
$this->db->from('employees e');
$this->db->join('salaries s', 'e.emp_no = s.emp_no', 'inner');
$this->db->where('e.birth_date > 1963-01-01');
$this->db->where('s.salary > 150000');

$result = $this->db->get();
```

**Edit:** The date string in the where clause is not quoted. Try updating the statement to quote the string, or pass it in as the second argument.

```
$this->db->where('e.birth_date > "1963-01-01"');
```

or

```
$this->db->where('e.birth_date >', '1963-01-01');
```

I am assuming this is the correct format mask for your date column in your database.

Comment: I originally added the e after employees, I was trying different things and forgot to include it when pasting it here. This gives me 15 names while running the sql query in phpmyadmin only returns 3.

Comment: @ethio I see that the date string is not quoted in the statement. You should quote the string, or pass it in as the second argument. I have updated the answer.

Comment: Yes, that's what I did and answered this question, thanks anyway.

Comment: @ethio Excellent. You are encourage to mark correct answer if one was provided.

Comment: I left an answer 45 minutes before your edit, I'm going to mark that as my answer.

Answer (score 0):

it is easy if active record is confusing you. You can simple use query function

```
$query  =   "SELECT 
                DISTINCT first_name,
                last_name 
            FROM employees e 
            INNER JOIN salaries s ON e.emp_no = s.emp_no 
            WHERE e.birth_date > '1963-01-01' 
            AND s.salary>150000";
$this->db->query($query);
```